# Filter Sub Array of Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, filter

I am trying to filter a sub array of a parent array and my results are coming back empty. I am trying to find matches to the color_family.

My array looks like:

```
const arr =[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "acf": {
      "product_colors": [
        {
          "color_family": "grey"
        },
        {
          "color_family": "taupe"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 456,
    "acf": {
      "product_colors": [
        {
          "color_family": "red"
        },
        {
          "color_family": "taupe"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

What I am filtering on is

```
const findColors = ["grey", "taupe"]
```

What I have tried with no luck is

```
const res = arr.filter(
  x => x.acf.product_colors.find(
    color_family => findColors.includes(color_family)
  )
)
```

This is returning no results when it should return 2 results. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think you have a typo x.acf.product_solors.find(  ==> x.acf.product_colors.find(

Comment: It was just a typo in the question. My code does not have the typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the typo, the param to the `find` argument is an object with `color_family`:

```
const res = arr.filter(x => x.acf.product_colors.find(col => {
  return findColors.includes(col.color_family);
}))
```